# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, autolayout

Can anybody help me understanding this Autolayout exception?

Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this:
 (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the

```
UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b3c030f30 H:[UIImageView:0x7f9b3c042530(80)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b3c04c980 UIImageView:0x7f9b3c042530.leading == UIView:0x7f9b39ef83e0.leadingMargin - 8>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b3c03be80 H:[UIImageView:0x7f9b3c042530]-(8)-[UILabel:0x7f9b3c03c520'Distance']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b39ef6d30 H:[UILabel:0x7f9b3c03c520'Distance']-(9)-[UILabel:0x7f9b3c03c330'Hip Hop']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b39ecdf60 UILabel:0x7f9b3c03c330'Hip Hop'.width == UILabel:0x7f9b39eef850'Price'.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b39ecdfb0 UILabel:0x7f9b3c03c330'Hip Hop'.width == UILabel:0x7f9b3c03c520'Distance'.width>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b39eed730 H:[UILabel:0x7f9b3c03c330'Hip Hop']-(9)-[UILabel:0x7f9b39eef850'Price']>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b39eed780 UIView:0x7f9b39ef83e0.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7f9b39eef850'Price'.trailing - 3>",
"<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b39edf060 h=--& v=--& H:[UIView:0x7f9b39ef83e0(50)]>"
)
```

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

```
 <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f9b3c030f30 H:[UIImageView:0x7f9b3c042530(80)]>
```

Help Appreciated.

Comment: Man why down vote?? None of the existing question on SO was able to make it clear properly..

Comment: I guess the down vote is because this is a VERY common question on Stack Overflow and the error actually tells you where to look in the documentation. `(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)`

Comment: Deleting the height constraint of the `UIImageView` or decreasing its priority would possibly fix the problem.

Comment: @gabbler it didn't get fixed either by removing height constraint or by decreasing its height priority but your comment probably gave me the hint to lower its width priority which finally fixed the problem.

Comment: Yeah good luck with that, without even a screenshot

Comment: @Andy hahaha i thought above info is enough to understand the problem... but down vote haunts me..

Comment: @pankaj downvote is not mine, don't look at me like this! Certainly constraints you showed are good enough for debugging but even better if you show the picture so we can clearly associate constraints with UI elements.

Comment: @Andy No buddy i am not complaining you. I always praises people like you who atleast tries to solve others problem...Tx buddy

Comment: @pankaj so nice of you :-)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the view is that you're adding in code you should add the line...

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

Comment: @pankaj did you try it? What about this line would stop AutoLayout from working?

Comment: and also i haven't added any view through code. every thing is been added via storyboard

Comment: I am just a newbie to AutoLayout thats why i was not sure about it but first let me try it.

Comment: Ah, in that case you have added a view in storyboard without adding auto layout constraints to it.

Comment: Its basically a collection view cell in collection view and i have added constraints to it and its also not showing any warning in storyboard for this viewController

Comment: Yeah, you have a view that is 50 pixels wide and the contents of it is trying to either make it bigger or smaller. It's hard to tell without seeing the storyboard file.